# where is my apk? codename one

Tags: build, apk, codenameone

After finish my code on Intellijidea with Codename One and test on simulator I am want to create the apk (on this case i will work with android) .
Is my first time on CN1. I am new even programming

I choose Send Android Build and I receive the following message:

```
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\java" -Xmx128m -Xss2m "-Dant.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant" "-Dant.library.dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\android\platforms\android-20\android.jar;C:\android\platforms\android-20\data\res;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-antlr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-jai.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-javamail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-jmf.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-jsch.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-junit4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-swing.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant-testutil.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\ant\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2 -logger com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaAntLogger2 -inputhandler com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler -buildfile C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build.xml build-for-android-device
  build.xml
  description
  import
  fail
  property
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  -pre-init
  property
  property
  property
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  installLibs
  -init-private
  property
  property
  property
  -init-user
  property
  property
  property
  -init-project
  property
  property
  -init-macrodef-property
  macrodef
  -do-init
  available
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  property
  property
  property
  property
  condition
  property
  property
  property
  property
  property
  condition
  property
  property
  property
  property
  condition
  path
  condition
  condition
  property
  property
  property
  property
  available
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  -post-init
  -init-check
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  fail
  -init-ap-cmdline-properties
  property
  property
  property
  property
  property
  property
  condition
  -init-macrodef-javac-with-processors
  -init-macrodef-javac-without-processors
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-javac
  macrodef
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-test-impl
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-junit-init
  condition
  condition
  -init-macrodef-junit-single
  -init-test-properties
  property
  property
  property
  -init-macrodef-junit-batch
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-junit
  -init-macrodef-junit-impl
  macrodef
  Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3:test-impl
  -init-macrodef-testng
  -init-macrodef-testng-impl
  -init-macrodef-test
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-junit-debug
  -init-macrodef-junit-debug-batch
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-junit-debug-impl
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-test-debug-junit
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-testng-debug
  -init-macrodef-testng-debug-impl
  -init-macrodef-test-debug-testng
  -init-macrodef-test-debug
  -init-debug-args
  property
  condition
  condition
  condition
  condition
  -init-macrodef-nbjpda
  macrodef
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-debug
  macrodef
  -init-macrodef-java
  macrodef
  -init-presetdef-jar
  presetdef
  -init-ap-cmdline-supported
  -init-ap-cmdline
  property
  init
  -deps-clean-init
  property
  delete
  deps-clean
  mkdir
  touch
  property
  antcall
  description
  import
  fail
  property
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  -warn-already-built-clean
  propertyfile
  Updating property file: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\built-clean.properties
  -do-clean
  delete
  Deleting directory C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build
  delete
  refresh-libs
  delete
  Deleting directory C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\lib\impl
  installLibs
  -post-clean
  clean
  copy-android-override
  mkdir
  Created dir: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\classes
  mkdir
  copy
  copy
  copy-libs
  copy
  -deps-jar-init
  property
  delete
  deps-jar
  mkdir
  touch
  property
  antcall
  description
  import
  fail
  property
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  taskdef
  -warn-already-built-jar
  propertyfile
  Updating property file: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\built-jar.properties
  -check-automatic-build
  available
  -clean-after-automatic-build
  -verify-automatic-build
  -pre-pre-compile
  mkdir
  -pre-compile
  echo
  Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
              code size and wider device support
  mkdir
  Created dir: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\tmp
  javac
  Compiling 3 source files to C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\tmp
  -copy-persistence-xml
  -compile-depend
  -do-compile
  j2seproject3:javac
  sequential
  property
  mkdir
  Created dir: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\empty
  javac
  Compiling 3 source files to C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\classes
  : [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
  1 warning
  copy
  Copying 1 file to C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build\classes
  -post-compile
  delete
  delete
  delete
  mkdir
  mkdir
  mkdir
  javac
  compile
  -pre-jar
  -pre-pre-jar
  dirname
  mkdir
  Created dir: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\dist
  -do-jar-with-manifest
  -do-jar-without-manifest
  j2seproject1:jar
  Building jar: C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\dist\IOS_Catedral.jar
  -do-jar-with-mainclass
  -do-jar-with-libraries-create-manifest
  tempfile
  touch
  -do-jar-with-libraries-copy-manifest
  -do-jar-with-libraries-set-main
  manifest
  -do-jar-with-libraries-set-splashscreen
  -init-macrodef-copylibs
  macrodef
  -do-jar-with-libraries-pack
  -do-jar-with-libraries-delete-manifest
  delete
  -do-jar-with-libraries
  -post-jar
  jar
  clean-override
  delete
  build-for-android-device
  codeNameOne

  Ant build completed with one warning in 18s at 24/01/2016 11:10 AM
```

I am Lost, was my apk downloaded? If not is because the warning?
How I fix it?

I cant find the solution on the web. I apretiate any help

Comment: I will suggest you use Netbeans, since you're new to programming. Codenameone is not as stable with IntelliJ as it is with Eclipse and Netbeans. I can't even figure out what the issue is from the log posted, especially the whole repetition.

Comment: I install Netbeans as works better. The apk is online, and I r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the [Codename One build server](https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html) for the build?

See this [creating a hello world app with intellij walkthru](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-basic-hello-world-application--send-it-to-my-device-using-intellij-idea.html) video.

A similar but [newer version with NetBeans](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-basic-hello-world-application--send-it-to-my-device-using-netbeans.html).

Comment: I installed Netbeans and received the message to check the build server. On IntelliJ the notification never arrives